# big ddply, appropriate alternative

Tags: r, plyr, lapply, sapply

I have a `list` of `data.frames`. Each `data.frame` is not very big ~150,000 rows.  But my list has over 1000s of these `data.frames`.

a `data.frame` looks like:

```
comp <- read.table(text = " G T H S B
                             1 1 1 1 x1
                             1 1 1 2 x2
                             1 2 6 1 x3
                             1 2 6 2 x4
                             2 1 7 1 x1
                             2 2 8 2 x2
                             2 2 8 1 x1
                             2 3 9 2 x2",header=TRUE,stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

so a list is:

```
complist <- list(comp,comp,comp)
```

I want to know for every `data.frame`, (`comp`), the length of `B` for each `S` in each `H` in each `T` in each `G`.

so for my small practice I use:

```
library(plyr)
listresults <- lapply(complist, function(x) {
                                res <- ddply(x, .(G,T,H,S),
                                function(z) data.frame(resultcol = length(z$B)) )
                                            } )
```

But on my larger list this is bruuutally long, could someone help me find a quicker way? `Aggregate` is not the option here, and I have been failing with a `sapply(split))` alternative to the `ddply`. Suggestions even if not actual code will be just as helpful to me.

Comment: +1 for all. to start `data.table` approach actually finished, although it will take some learning.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a situation where `data.table` might be a very good option. `data.table` has consistently shown to be blisteringly fast, much more so that `plyr`. There are many examples here on SO, see e.g.:

- [how to operate with a subset of an R dataframe in long format?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13220395/how-to-operate-with-a-subset-of-an-r-dataframe-in-long-format)
- [Using plyr, doMC, and summarise() with very big dataset?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8669345/using-plyr-domc-and-summarise-with-very-big-dataset)
- or [a blogpost of mine](http://www.numbertheory.nl/2011/10/28/comparison-of-ave-ddply-and-data-table/).

This is just a very small portion of the information available, you can check out the documentation of `data.table`, or look at the `[r][data.table]` tags on SO.

Comment: thanks for the links, looks like I'm going to have to just learn data.table!

Comment: The 'data.table' package is very good for summarizing this way.  Keep in mind that you can often even beat the performance of 'data.table' by reformatting your data to specifically suit your problem.

Answer (score 6):

Using `data.table` may get this faster. Here's how you can do it.

```
require(data.table)
o <- lapply(1:length(complist), function(i) { 
    dt <- data.table(complist[[i]], key=c("S", "H", "T", "G"))
    dt[, list(resultcol = .N), by=c("S", "H", "T", "G")]
})
```

Comment: +1 did not know about the `.N` shortcut for length. This is just an `nrow`?

Comment: @Arun Just for information, is there a reason for the order of the keys (SHTG instead of GTHS) ?

Answer (score 2):

One try with using `data.table` :

```
lapply(complist, function(df) {
  df <- data.table(df, key=c("G","T","H","S"))
  df[,length(B),by=c("G","T","H","S")]
})
```

Disclaimer : it's the first time I'm using `data.table`, so be careful with this answer :)